# excel spreadsheet data to web form

Tags: excel

I'm looking to place my company's trailer inventory on a few free classified ad sites.  Our inventory database (filemaker) can export data into an excel spreadsheet (column A-Make, B-Model, C-Year, etc.) including the URLs of the photos of each trailer.

Our dealer sites allow for bulk uploading through XML and that works great.

My problem is on the smaller free classified ad sites that have a web form that needs filled out (the example I'm using here has text fields and drop-down menus, but other sites have check boxes and radio buttons) then submitted for each individual trailer (about 90 trailers).  I'm wondering how I can use the data in my spreadsheet to auto-fill the form with the information in row 1, submit it, re-navigate back to the form and repeat the process with the info in row 2 and so on. I know that I'm going to have to tailor my data and columns to fit each site (match column names to field names and change relevant data to match drop down options, etc.).

**edit Also (although not necessary) it would be nice if it was possible to have my photo URLs entered as well (if at all possible).

I've created a "test" account on http://www.horseclicks.com. Once logged in you have to click on "My Trailers" on the left and then the "add" button

user: excelhelp

pass: excel

Any takers??

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely answer your question, but would save you some time entering the forms manually. If you know the names of input tags on the form you want to fill out, you can write a Javascript that will fill out the form for you: i.e., document.getElementById('your_name').value=Name[x]; etc.

In that example, Name would be an array that would contain a list of the names you wanted to put in the input field "your_name".  You can easily turn an Excel sheet into a Javascript array by exporting to CSV and cut/paste into your code.  Make it so that the value of x increases by 1 each time the script is ran.

Take your whole javascript, and turn it into one line that starts with "javascript:" and place this as a bookmark in your toolbar.  Now you can go to the form, hit the your bookmark button and it will fill out the form. Hit submit, go back to the form, hit the button again...

Comment: This sound like an awesome answer if i can get it to work.  JavaScript isn't really my particular brand of vodka though.  I have a sample inventory xls file that i wasn't sure how to include with my thread (no sure if this site supports the feature), or even email to someone for an example to be made of it (it only has 2 trailer entries with the address and phone # changed).